# ListView with RelativeLayout not highlighting background on press

Tags: android, listview, android-relativelayout

I want to have a list of elements (using a ListView) and each element in list is styled with a relative layout. Currently, the items are being displayed correctly, however, for some reason the listview items dont glow green when they're clicked. Why is this?

I have removed all code to minimals and it still does this.

**Activity class**

```
package com.test;

import android.app.Activity;

public class My_ListView extends Activity
{
    private ListView_Adapter listViewAdapter;
    private ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_listview);


        // initialise the list-view object
        listViewAdapter = new ListView_Adapter(this);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        listView.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);


        for (int i=0;i<20;i++)
        {
            listViewAdapter.add("item "+i);
        }

    }
    public void clicked(View v)
    {
        v.setBackgroundColor(0xFF0000FF);
    }
}
```

**The listview item adapter class**

```
package com.test;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ListView_Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{
    public ListView_Adapter(Context c)
    {
        super(c, R.layout.my_listview_item);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View row = convertView;
        StationFinder_ListViewItemHolder holder = null;

        if (row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_listview_item, parent, false);
            holder = new StationFinder_ListViewItemHolder(row);
            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (StationFinder_ListViewItemHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        holder.populateFrom(getItem(position));

        return row;
    }

    static class StationFinder_ListViewItemHolder
    {
        private TextView destination = null;

        StationFinder_ListViewItemHolder(View row)
        {
            destination = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        }

        void populateFrom(String locationDistance)
        {
            destination.setText(locationDistance);
        }

    }
}
```

**my_listview.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <ListView android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

**my_listview_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="clicked"
    >
    <TextView android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may have to call `invalidate()` after setting the background color.

You may want to do this instead by setting the [listSelector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android%3alistSelector) and possibly [drawSelectorOnTop](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android%3adrawSelectorOnTop) for your ListView. That way the selection/deselection and clicks will be handled in the normal manner.

**Edit** - also, since you're using a ListView, you probably want to listen for clicks by setting an `OnItemClickListener` on your ListView.

Comment: ah the coloring was only being done to check that the item was infact being clicked. I tested without that and it still didn't highlight

Comment: also invalidate doesnt change anything, nor does setting drawSelectorOnTop=true

Comment: what about setting a breakpoint in clicked() to see if it's actually getting called?

Comment: yea, clicked() is being called, but listviews are automatically meant to color the background on press right? This one doesn't and I want to make it do that again

Comment: I found removing the onClick function call now allows the background to be colored green on pressed. Thanks